# How to reasonably handle RuntimeExceptionS from a 3rd-party API?

Tags: java, exception, gson

I'm using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in my API. `Gson#fromJson` throws a run-time exception, namely, `JsonSyntaxException`.

> **JsonSyntaxException**
>
> This exception is raised when Gson attempts to read (or write) a malformed JSON element.

It's expected that calling code will send my API malformed JSON. What's the best way to handle such a situation? My current thinking would be to catch `JsonSyntaxException` and re-throw a custom checked exception.

Obviously this situation is common place. What is the preferred way to tackle this problem?

Comment: i think u got it right...as long as malformed url is really "expected". but how do u define expected in this case

Comment: @Suraj Chandran - callers are passing me JSON that doesn't necessarily go through any validation. I'm then passing this to `gson`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach (about wrapping with a custom checked exception) is fine. But unless malformed input is *expected* and should be handled by callers (which is your case, but not necessarily in general for other readers here), using an unchecked exception is better.

Comment: so really it's a case by case decision. In my case, I'm expected to inform my caller of the exception, yet, on some other occasion, as is the case with `gson` and my own API, it might not be totally correct to handle the exception.

Comment: Indeed, as with most things in programming, there's no one-size-fits-all solution. :-D